# How to reduce table width?

Tags: tables, tabularx, width

I'm trying to add a table to my IEEE paper but its width is too much. Please help me fix the width to make it fit.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
.
.
.
.

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}{|c c c c c c|} 
     \hline
     Feature 1 & Feature 2 & Accuracy & Precision & Recall & Specificity \\ [0.5ex] 
     \hline\hline
     original dna size & compressed dna size & 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.999 \\
     \hline
     original dna size & compression ratio & 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.999 \\ [1ex] 
     \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
.
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're using `tabularx` you need to use at least one column that uses `X` to reach the total width goal, without an `X`-type column `tabularx` is just a `tabular` with extra input.

Comment: Not particularly. I'm not able to understand which solution to use and it looks like it doesn't help my case. Could you please suggest a solution for my scenario?

Comment: @Skillmon, how do I use X and what is the meaning of it?

Comment: I'd guess that the columns `Accuracy`, `Precision`, etc. will store numbers, so you might want to use a column type that neatly aligns numbers, like the `S`-type provided by `siunitx`.

Comment: Instead of a `c`-column use an `X` column, but that won't solve things for you here, it'll just look terrible.

Comment: @Skillmon, Please tell me what changes I need to make in the LaTex code to use S and X-types.

Comment: @Skillmon, Yep it made things worse.

Comment: Why do you need to have a table that is only `0.3\textwidth` wide? Also, could you please post a compilable example (your code misses `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`, and the required packages to compile (in this case only `tabularx`).

Comment: @skillmon, I have edited the code. Please see it now.

Comment: @SujithK also, some better dummy data than `xxx` would be good as well, are the four following columns all numeric? The closer your MWE is to your actual document (while keeping it minimal, so no need to add text, just make your table closer to the real thing, no need to use your real data, just something close to it) the better we can suggest stuff.

Comment: Also, in your definition of `\BibTeX`: Don't use `\rm` and `\sc`, those macros are deprecated/unsupported by LaTeX since more than a decade! Instead use `\rmfamily` and `\scshape`.

Comment: @Skillmon, data for the table is updated. Ok I will use \rmfamily instead thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
I delete my first version of answer since was based on @Skillmon comments which he later converted in excellent answer (+1). So I decide first to delete mine.

But now renew it with an example, how can be used a relative new package `tabularray` for your table design:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}             % <--- new, used version 2021Q
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}  % <--- new

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\begin{tblr}{colsep=4pt,
             colspec={@{} X[l] X[l] *{4}{S[table-format=1.3]} @{}},
             }
     \toprule
Feature 1   & Feature 2 & {{{Accuracy}}} & {{{Precision}}} &{{{ Recall}}} & {{{Specificity}}} \\
    \midrule
original dna size   & compressed dna size   & 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.999 \\
original dna size   & compression ratio     & 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.999 \\ 
     \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following makes the following changes to your table:

- Use `\linewidth` instead of `0.3\textwidth` as the width the table might take
- Actually make use of the `X`-type columns by defining a new column type (called `L`) that'll be a left-aligned `X`-type column (this way TeX won't try to set the contents of these columns flush, which would only throw overfull box warnings as that's nearly impossible with narrow columns)
- Use the `S`-type column provided by `siunitx` for the numeric data (the `table-format=1.3` means numbers have 1 digit before the decimal separator and 3 digits afterwards).
- Drop the standard rules provided by the LaTeX kernel, instead use the rules `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` provided by `booktabs`
- To ease reading of the table put `\addlinespace` (also provided by `booktabs`) between rows which need more than a single line of text.
- Reduce the space between columns to 3/4ths using `\setlength\tabcolsep{.75\tabcolsep}`.
- Put the `\caption` above the tabular (that's what `IEEEtran` wants, compare the spacing of the caption to yours) and put the `\label` inside the mandatory argument of `\caption` (that is more robust in general).
- Don't use `h!` only as the placement, instead I used `htp!` (LaTeX will turn `h!` to `ht!` anyway, and allowing no `p` leads to problems most of the times if your table gets too big). If you want "absolutely here and no where else" you should use `H` provided by the `float` package instead.

Everything combined:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{duckuments}% dummy content for the text, don't use it in your document

\begin{document}
\blindduck

\begin{table}[htp!]% never use just h!
  \centering
  \caption{caption\label{tab:my_label}}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{.75\tabcolsep}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{L L *{4}{S[table-format=1.3]}} 
    \toprule
    Feature 1 & Feature 2 & {Accuracy} & {Precision} & {Recall} & {Specificity} \\
    \midrule
    original dna size & compressed dna size & 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.999 \\
    \addlinespace
    original dna size & compression ratio & 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.999 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\blindduck
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the duckuments package :-). Does the numbers are CM or Times?

Comment: @Skillmon, thank you very much!! Your answer was extremely helpful.

Comment: @Sebastiano whatever the class sets, in this case the family is `ptm` so times.